# Neither proxychains and torsocks work in Mac

Tags: macos, proxy, homebrew, tor, socks-proxy

I installed proxychains via brew:

```
$ brew install proxychains-ng
```

and torsocks:

```
$ brew install tor torsocks
```

But they either don't work.

If I test with:

```
$ proxychains4 http https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
```

Output tells me that ip is my real one, not the tor one.

Also,

```
$ torsocks http https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
```

has the same output.

But if I manually put proxy inside "httpie" like this:

```
$ http --proxy=https:socks5://localhost:9050 https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
```

It finally works and gives me the tor ip output. So this is not a tor problem. I also tested http proxies with proxychains, and output gives me my real ip. So connection works, but it is done with my real address, not the proxied.

It seems either torsocks and proxychains are transparent. It's like I'm executing "http" without them.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior.  The README says not all programs will work with the "hack-style" unofficial repo.
https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/blob/master/README
HttpPie needs to be told which proxy to use and would work better with an iptables-based proxy chain.